# Specify file uploading path in php

Tags: php

I am doing a project in PHP. I want to upload files to server. My PHP file is residing in  this folder:

`http://www.example.com/ssl/`

html code is

```
    <tr> 
    <td width="157" align="right"><font class="text2" size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Choose file:</b></font></td>
    <td width="337"> 
    <input type="file" name="Code_1" size="25" maxlength="100">
    </td>
    </tr>

<input type="submit" name="Senden" value="Submit">
```

php code is

```
if (isset($_POST["Senden"])) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Code_1"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["Code_1"]["name"]);
echo "File uploaded";
}
}
else{
    echo "File not uploaded"
}
```

This code is working and file is uploaded to http://www.example.com/ssl/uploads/

I want to upload files to:

`http://www.example.com/uploads/`.

How can I do this? I dont know how to specify the path. I have used the absolute path, but it is not working. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be missing the code from the post!

Comment: how about you add code that shows what you did so far?

Comment: Although deceze has give you pretty much what you should need to know, we don't know if you need more, and this question doesn't help other people with similar problems without the code. Please provide what you've done so far.

Comment: For later visitors: see php upload codes at [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the path in following way:

```
$folder =  "../images/stories/lab_excel/";
```

here, $folder is path.
Here is my upload function:

```
function upload($name,$tmp_name){   

    $fileextarr=explode('.',$name);
    $fileextarr[0];
    $fileext=$fileextarr[count($fileextarr)-1];
    $fpath = "../images/stories/lab_excel/";
    $filename = ereg_replace(" ","_",$fileextarr[0]).'.'.$fileext;



    if($fileext=="xls" || $fileext=="xlsx" || $fileext=="doc"|| $fileext=="docx" || $fileext=="jpeg" || $fileext=="png" || $fileext=="gif" || $fileext=="tiff" || $fileext=="bmp" || $fileext=="jpg")
    {
        $uploadedfile = $filename;

    }


    $folder =  "../images/stories/lab_excel/";
    $result =   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], $folder.$filename);

    /*echo $folder.$_FILES['excel']['name'];
    die();*/

    if($result){
    $msg="File Uploaded Successfully";
        return $folder.$filename;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And This is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your code the only change you need is

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Code_1"]["tmp_name"],"../uploads/" . $_FILES["Code_1"]["name"]);
```

So put **../** before `uploads/`.

See upload codes at [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).